# Парсинг картинок

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, изображения, requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep

def getImages(url):
  sleep(2)
  HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}

  responce = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.content, 'html.parser')
  items = soup.findAll('div', class_='reader-view__container')
  comps = []

  for item in items:
    comps.append(item.find('img').get('src'))

  print(comps)

getImages('https://hentailib.me/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/v1/c1?page=1')
```

мне нужно спарсить все изображения со странички сайта. Но из-за загрузки сайта это не получается. Я пробовал ставить таймер чтоб переждать загрузку, но это не работает. Но при заходе на сайт через браузер загрузка происходит примерно за секунду.

Comment: `Я пробовал ставить таймер чтоб переждать загрузку, но это не работает.`, а вы сохраните `responce.content` в файл: `open('rs.html', 'wb').write(responce.content)` и посмотрите в файле есть ли ссылки на те картинки?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Анализ

Сами данные по картинкам в [html](/questions/tagged/html) не находятся, их нужно искать среди [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) кода. Т.е. при выполнении скриптов, страница будет частично сформирована из js-кода.

Картинки описаны в двух местах:

1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот кусок из **1.**:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "media": {
        "id": 21928,
        "slug": "koshkodevochki-eto-lozh",
        "type": 1,
        "caution": 2
    },
    "bookmark": null,
    "current": {
        "id": 468545,
        "volume": 1,
        "number": "1",
        "index": 1
    },
    "next": {
        "id": 482546,
        "volume": 1,
        "number": "2",
        "url": "https:\/\/hentailib.me\/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh\/v1\/c2"
    },
    "prev": null,
    "img": {
        "url": "\/manga\/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh\/chapters\/468545\/",
        "server": "compress",
        "supportWebp": true
    },
    "servers": {
        "main": "https:\/\/img2.hentailib.me",
        "secondary": "https:\/\/img2.hentailib.me",
        "compress": "https:\/\/img3.hentailib.me",
        "fourth": "https:\/\/img4.hentailib.me"
    }
}
```

А вот из **2.**:

```
[{"p":1,"u":"02_iips.png"},{"p":2,"u":"03_67pz.png"},{"p":3,"u":"04_v5SN.png"},{"p":4,"u":"05_0dsy.png"},{"p":5,"u":"06_guTg.png"},{"p":6,"u":"07_cCtQ.png"},{"p":7,"u":"08_EQUb.png"},{"p":8,"u":"09_UfrK.png"},{"p":9,"u":"10_bffa.png"},{"p":10,"u":"11_7iDq.png"},{"p":11,"u":"12_bwHN.png"},{"p":12,"u":"13_ENhV.png"},{"p":13,"u":"14_wisV.png"},{"p":14,"u":"15_uVKc.png"},{"p":15,"u":"16_DOEE.png"},{"p":16,"u":"17_D3O1.png"},{"p":17,"u":"18_Y8S2.png"},{"p":18,"u":"19_g7SA.png"},{"p":19,"u":"20_B9qA.png"},{"p":20,"u":"21_IhKI.png"},{"p":21,"u":"22_sUOK.png"},{"p":22,"u":"23_PY78.png"}]
```

---

## Парсинг

Теперь вытащим эти данные из страницы используя регулярку и распарсим в JSON:

```
import re
import json
import sys

import requests


url = 'https://hentailib.me/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/v1/c1?page=1'
rs = requests.get(url)

info = re.search('window.__info = (.+?);', rs.text)
pages = re.search('window.__pg = (.+?);', rs.text)

info = json.loads(info.group(1))
pages = json.loads(pages.group(1))

print(info)
# {'page': 1, 'media': {'id': 21928, 'slug': 'koshkodevochki-eto-lozh', 'type': 1, ...

print(pages)
# [{'p': 1, 'u': '02_iips.png'}, {'p': 2, 'u': '03_67pz.png'}, {'p': 3, 'u': ...
```

## Обработка

Нужно из этих двух коллекций сгенерировать URL. Чтобы точно знать как делается, нужно найти `javascript`, ответственный за это, но мне не охото и я составлю на основе того URL, что увидел, когда открыл страницу сайта:

```
https://img3.hentailib.me//manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/02_iips.png
```

У меня получился такой алгоритм:

```
info = json.loads(info.group(1))
pages = json.loads(pages.group(1))

url_chapter = info['img']['url']
url_base = info['servers']['main'] + url_chapter

items = [url_base + p['u'] for p in pages]
```

## [Всё вместе:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/fb495a2da5359f17d3a000870334e9f2143f0da3/html_parsing/hentailib_me.py#L14)

```
import re
import json
from typing import List

import requests


def get_images(url: str) -> List[str]:
    rs = requests.get(url)

    info = re.search('window.__info = (.+?);', rs.text)
    if not info:
        print('[#] Not found window.__info!')
        return []

    pages = re.search('window.__pg = (.+?);', rs.text)
    if not pages:
        print('[#] Not found window.__pg!')
        return []

    info = json.loads(info.group(1))
    pages = json.loads(pages.group(1))

    url_chapter = info['img']['url']
    url_base = info['servers']['main'] + url_chapter

    return [url_base + p['u'] for p in pages]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://hentailib.me/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/v1/c1?page=1'
    items = get_images(url)

    print(f'Images ({len(items)}):')
    for i, url in enumerate(items, 1):
        print(f'    {i}. {url}')
```

Результат (**осторожно по ссылкам переходите - там контент для взрослых**):

```
Images (22):
    1. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/02_iips.png
    2. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/03_67pz.png
    3. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/04_v5SN.png
    4. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/05_0dsy.png
    5. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/06_guTg.png
    6. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/07_cCtQ.png
    7. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/08_EQUb.png
    8. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/09_UfrK.png
    9. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/10_bffa.png
    10. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/11_7iDq.png
    11. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/12_bwHN.png
    12. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/13_ENhV.png
    13. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/14_wisV.png
    14. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/15_uVKc.png
    15. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/16_DOEE.png
    16. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/17_D3O1.png
    17. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/18_Y8S2.png
    18. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/19_g7SA.png
    19. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/20_B9qA.png
    20. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/21_IhKI.png
    21. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/22_sUOK.png
    22. https://img2.hentailib.me/manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/23_PY78.png
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось! Я даже большую часть кода понял)

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, почему вы тут не использовали headers?

Comment: @Tri, можно было, но не было нужды :) Как вариант, вы можете хотя бы User-Agent заполнять, чтобы не палиться ботом :)

Comment: ххввхвхвхвхав мне как раз хетай и нужен был

Comment: правда немного другой но всеже

Comment: это прекрасно))

Comment: @Alexalexeev, спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def getImages(url):  
  HEADERS = {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
        'Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept-Language': 'en',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'origin': 'https://best.aliexpress.ru',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'referer': 'https://best.aliexpress.ru/',
        'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
        }
```

Далее всё как у вас.
Вас сайт просто определяет как парсер, а нужно притвориться браузером с человеком. :)

**PS.**

У меня не пустой массив

Вот скрин с Юпитера-ноутбука:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выводит пустой массив

Comment: @Tri  читайте ответ выше, дописал - там скриншот. К комментарию скрин не смог прикрепить.

Comment: простите, ошибся. Но это все равно не то что мне нужно.

Comment: @Tri  так да. :)  Вы просто не полностью задачу поставили, а я не заглянул на страничку глазами.  gil9red выше вытянул вам полностью картинки. Контент, конечно, ещё тот.. :)

Comment: сможете помочь? Я смог реализовать получения списка со списками(список с изображениями из каждой главы) я начал скачивать изображения, первое, а иногда и второе загружаются, а другие нет. У меня есть подозрение что и тут сайт узнает в парсере программу, а не человека. Как это обойти? У меня есть идея: попробовать менять user-agent при каждой загрузке изображения, но как этот user-agent генерировать?
парсер https://drive.google.com/file/d/148jUZaSa694kIksCQ0_P6mPSPJau-oRd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: у каждого свои вкусы)

Comment: @Tri не понятно, зачем каждый раз менять? Ведь человек когда смотрит через браузер - он ничего не меняет, а смотрит все картинки. Есть конечно небольшая вероятность, что картинки генерятся из какой то базы, но скорее всего они лежат на сайте статикой. Зачем напрягать движок еще и этим? Хотя... Если статика - то как их защитить от скачивания? да никак. Адрес если известен - то он должен отдавать и картинку. Значит можно рассматривать только вариант с картинками из базы. Попозже попробую ваш скрипт запустить. сейчас у меня тут дети бегают, а картинки специфические.

Comment: это конечно же ваше право мне не отвечать, но может вы забыли?

Comment: @Tri у меня тут цейтнот. Надо сдавать проект. Если вам не горит - то подождите. Посмотрю. Вроде они закрыли ту "дырку" которую прошлый раз нашёл gil9red. Теперь придётся искать как скрипты обращаются к API и пробовать делать такие же запросы.  Смогу порыться только когда будет больше времени. Сейчас до четверга - совсем никак. Попробуйте пока найти скрипты JS которые тянут список картинок. Может у вас получится. Дальше я подключусь - быстрее будет.

Comment: спасибо, постараюсь когда будет время найти скрипты.

Comment: Простите, я не смог найти. Может это прозвучит глупо, но я просто копировал код со всех скриптов которые я находил и старался с помощью функции поиска в ворде найти "iips" - это часть ссылки на первое изображение. Может они шифруют?

Comment: @Tri нет, там не будет "iips". Думаю адрес будет формировать API полностью. Надо проверить все вызовы в JS сервера. Один из этих вызовов вернёт список картинок. Вряд ли они будут шифровать... если же заморочатся ещё и шифром.. то всё... никак. :) Но, надеюсь, до шифра таки дело не дойдёт. Хлопотно это шифровать, да расшифровывать ключами.

Comment: @Tri вам похоже опять повезло - программа, та которая выше опять заработала, значит владельцы сайта не залатали брешь. Так что успевайте качать свои картинки.

Comment: Не получилось. Наверняка такое отношение к проекту не правильное, но это для меня не очень то и важно. Просто решил ради прикола попытаться спарсить картинки и заодно сделать конвертер в pdf чтобы потом читать на электронной книге.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на адрес самого изображения:

```
https://img3.hentailib.me//manga/koshkodevochki-eto-lozh/chapters/468545/09_UfrK.png
```

_UfrK на конце, это явно защита от такого вот банального скачивания.

Посмотрите на куки, там есть XSRF-TOKEN, пока вы его не получите, картинки вам никто не покажет.

В общем случае: при такой защите делаются 2 запроса, первый, на загрузку страницы и получение этого токена, а второй,  для получения нужного контента.

Comment: У меня открылась картинка по ссылке. На сайт до этого не заходил :)

Comment: я не очень понял как это сделать в моем случае. Сможете помочь кодом?